# Pyramid Framework (SQL Alchemy) - Making the tables globally available

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pylons, pyramid

Could someone please tell me how one can make table classes and 'dbsession()' created using sqlalchemy in pyramid available globally, so I can query those tables within my templates.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Given you should query in `views`and not in `templates` you can do something like this:

```
from myproject import models

def my_view(request):
    return {'models': models}
```

and in template access DBSession and your model classes with `models.DBSession` and `models.MyClass`